# Vue Js and Rails: Image upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vuejs2, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to upload an image to my rails API using the gem active storage and sending it as a FormData through my Vue Application. However, it gives an `param is missing or the value is empty` error even though all the parameters are being sent.

**Vue Js (Component)**

```
async onSubmit(e){
          const formData = await new FormData()
          formData.append('name', this.name)
          formData.append('description', this.description)
          formData.append('country_id', this.country[0].id)
          formData.append('image', this.selectedFile)
          this.addDish(formData);
      }
```

**Vuex**

```
async addDish({ commit }, formData){
        const response = await axios.post(URL,formData);
        commit('newDish', response.data);
    },
```

**Rails Model**

```
class Dish < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
end
```

**Rails Controller**

```
def create
dish = Dish.new(dish_params)
if dish.save
 render json: dish, status: :created
else
 render json: dish.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
end 

private
def dish_params
  params.require(:dish).permit(:name, :description, :country_id, :image)
end
```

**API error**

```
 Parameters: {"name"=>"teste", "description"=>"teste", "country_id"=>"1", 
"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00005584f2f458e0 
@tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20200619-4-o32kdp.png>, @original_filename="0.png",
 @content_type="image/png", 
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"0.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}
2020-06-19T06:20:28.183600+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-06-19T06:20:28.183538 #4]  INFO -- : [c510b9d0-df62-4479-a4ef-1b898d113fcc] 
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 163)
2020-06-19T06:20:28.184035+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-06-19T06:20:28.183978 #4] FATAL -- : [c510b9d0-df62-4479-a4ef-1b898d113fcc]
2020-06-19T06:20:28.184048+00:00 app[web.1]: [c510b9d0-df62-4479-a4ef-1b898d113fcc] 
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: dish):
```

Answer (score 0):

the error comes from the fact that you are requiring the key `:dish` on the request, but you are not sending it. lets see

in your rails controller you have this following `before_action`

```rb
def dish_params
  params.require(:dish).permit(:name, :description, :country_id, :image)
end
```

here you say that the request must have a key with the name dish, and that key must be a symbol with keys name, description, contryID, and image. so the request should be structrued this way

```
requestobject
   dish
       name
       description
       image
       contryID
```

But,in your front end you are not providing the `dish` key name in your request, rather you are spreading the content of your form to the request, so your request will end up like this

```
requestobject
   name
   description
   image
   contryID
```

as you see, all the values are present, but due to the `before_action` wanting them to be inside an object with `dish` name, thats why you get the error

```rb
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: dish):
```

as the error says, the dish key is undefined in the request.

The solution for this is that when  you send your request, insted of spreading the formdata inside the request, spread it inside the `dish` key name, as follows:

```rb
async addDish({ commit }, formData){
        const request = {
             dish: formData
         };

        const response = await axios.post(URL, request);
        commit('newDish', response.data);
    },
```

now as you see, the request object has a key with the name of `dish`, now your controller will be satisfied since the contract is now fulfilled

Comment: I'm getting the same error ```Parameters: {"dish"=>{}}
2020-06-19T14:55:19.341474+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-06-19T14:55:19.341407 #4]  INFO -- : [ebb67f43-368a-4645-9b04-e17fd31df267] Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 127)
2020-06-19T14:55:19.342393+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-06-19T14:55:19.342325 #4] FATAL -- : [ebb67f43-368a-4645-9b04-e17fd31df267]
2020-06-19T14:55:19.342394+00:00 app[web.1]: [ebb67f43-368a-4645-9b04-e17fd31df267] ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: dish):
```

Comment: did u try to log the value of `formData` before sending it. it seems that the value `formData` in empty as the error says

Comment: then, check when you commit your action to vuex, idk but it should not be empty